# How should I investigate a cause of crash on Bluemix?

Tags: crash, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, websphere-liberty

I got the following error messages when I pushed an app of Liberty for Java into Bluemix.

[Console]
an instance of the app crashed: failed to start exit status: -1, CRASHED

[cf events *APPNAME*]
index: 1, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to start, exit_status: -1
index: 2, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to start, exit_status: -1

a) Is there exit status code list? I can not find it.
b) This error, exit status = -1, sometimes occurred. What is it? How should I investigate this cause?

Answer (score 0):

On bluemix, you can use **cf logs appName** command to investigate the logs.
You can also use Monitoring and analytics for investigating the logs.
Read this article to get an idea of logging mechanism on bluemix -
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2014/10/accessing-application-logs-bluemix/

Comment: yashpandey,
Thank you for your response.
This error occurred at staging period.
I binded Monitering and Analytics service but I did not get any effective infomation from logs.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cf events appname` to see if there's any more crash related info. Ensure that you deployed the app with enough memory, as insufficient memory will cause a crash on startup.

Comment: RandalAnders,

Thank you for your response.
I got cf events log. A detail message was not included in log.
'2016-10-14T07:50:34.00+0000   app.crash          appname               index: 1, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to start, exit_status: -1'
'2016-10-14T07:50:34.00+0000   app.crash          appname               index: 2, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to start, exit_status: -1'
In OOM case, I usually get OOM message in log. "exit_status -1" was spectial code, I think. I guess that "exit_status -1" is took unexcepted error occurs. Is it correct?